# Filter based on columns that may not be there

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the following data.table structure.

```
demo <- data.table(a = rnorm(10),
                   b = rnorm(10)...
                   z = rnorm(10))
```

I can filter it with

```
data[a > -1.96 & b > -1.3 & c > -1.4...]
```

However sometimes multiple columns (e.g. `a`) will be missing. Is there a simple way of modifying my filter to allow for the possibility that the column doesn't exist? If the column doesn't exist, the filter would be ignored.

Comment: What criteria would you be using if the data doesn't exist?

Comment: Clarified OP: basically, if `a` doesn't exist, then no filter would occur based on the a column.

Comment: You can specify with `.SDcols`.  Can you give bit more info regarding the `filter` approach.  Are you doing this wiith an expression already created

Comment: Are you passing an expression string like this `expr1 <-  "a > -1.96 & b > -1.3 & c > -1.4"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a programmatic way to approach it, where the filter is built based on what columns are present. Not sure your application, but this could be easily adapted to pull in conditions from another source, rather than hard-coding them in.

The line `if(!(i %in% names(conditions))) next` tests if the column `i` in the data.table exists as an element of the `conditions` list.

```r
library(data.table)

demo <- data.table(a = rnorm(10),
                   b = rnorm(10),
                   c = rnorm(10),
                   d = rnorm(10))

conditions <- list(a = ">0.5",
                   b = "<0",
                   z = "<0.5")

filter = ""
cols <- colnames(demo)

for(i in cols){
  if(!(i %in% names(conditions))) next
  filter <- paste0(filter, i, conditions[i], " & ")
}
filter <- substr(filter, 1, nchar(filter) - 3)

demo[eval(parse(text = filter))]
```

Initially I was going to say test for the end of the conditions to break from the loop and not include the `&`, but this would perform that operation every time through the loop. Just removing the final three characters for the unneeded string `" & "` only has to happen once.

Comment: Went with a similar approach to this. 

`filter <- "TRUE";
    for (f in seq_len(nrow(filters))) {
        if (filters$column[f] %in% colnames(lapses) ) {
            filter <- paste(filter, 
                            paste0(filters$column[f], " == ", filters$value[f]), 
                            sep = " & ")
        }
    }`

Comment: you could also do this without the for-loop:
`used_cond <- conditions[names(conditions) %in% names(demo)]`
`filter <- paste0(names(used_cond), unlist(used_cond), collapse = " & ")`
With this you do not run into the problem with the ending " & ".

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
cols <- colnames(demo)
demo[ifelse("a" %in% cols, a > -1.96,TRUE) & ifelse("b" %in% cols, b > -1.3,TRUE) & ifelse("c" %in% cols, c > -1.4,TRUE),]
```

It is not a simple way regarding the number of letters added, but it is simple while talking about logic.